# Change action when combobox contains specific word

Tags: javascript, html, combobox

I am going to attempt to explain this a bit better than last time, as last time I did very, very badly!

So far I have code which brings up a combobox and a button. In my combobox, there is 3 options, called "StaffHome", "AdminHome" and "IntranetHome".

This is what I need to do:
If "StaffHome" is selected and the button is pressed, the page redirects to '/staffhome/index.html'

If "AdminHome" is selected and the button is pressed, the page redirects to '/adminhome/hyd/home.html'

And if "IntranetHome" is selected and the button is pressed, the page redirects to '/intrhme/index.html'.

I'd like to use JS to do this.

```
<form id="select">
    <select>
        <option value="staffhome">StaffHome</option>
        <option value="adminhome">AdminHome</option>
        <option value="intranethome">IntranetHome</option>
    </select>
    <button type="button">Redirect</button>
</form>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7VM3/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7VM3/

Comment: 1) post code in the question 2) format text better 3) tag with the allowed tech, so JavaScript AND jQuery if you want either or both. HTML cannot do what you want on its own

Comment: Thank you mplungjan, I'm new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the button an ID

For Plain JS give the select a name or ID

```
var actions =['/staffhome/index.html','/adminhome/hyd/home.html', '/intrhme/index.html']; 
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("but").onclick=function() {
    this.form.action=actions[this.form.folderSelect.selectedIndex]; // using name
    this.form.submit();
  }
}
```

Alternatively make the button a submit button and do

```
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("select").onsubmit=function() {
    this.action=actions[document.getElementById("folderSelect").selectedIndex]; // using ID
  }
}
```

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/hj3Vd/)

Comment: Hi mplungjan. Thanks for the quick response. Would you be able to add this to the jsfiddle so I can see where it goes? Sorry, I am a pure beginner!

Comment: mplungjan, if I upload my full code, can you check it for me and make it work? I am struggling with this!